# Armadillo (+BLAS) using GPU

Tags: gpu, blas, armadillo

Is it possible to run armadillos calculations using GPU? Is there any way to use the GPU blas libraries (for example cuBLAS) with armadillo? Just a note, I am totally new to GPU programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not.

You cannot take code for the *cpu* and assume it runs on the *gpu* as both have completely different memory models, hardware, programming styles etc pp.

Comment: as mentioned in the other answer and the FAQ, you can use NVBLAS or ACML: http://arma.sourceforge.net/faq.html

Comment: Keep in mind that I wrote the answer in August of 2013; there have been dozens of Armadillo (and CUDA !!) releases since.

Answer (score 22):

The current accepted answer is outdated. Comming with CUDA 6 (at the moment Release Candidate status), there is a true drop-in replacement called NVBLAS which takes care about GPU interaction and also works in combination with armadillo. You can use NVBLAS by linking your program agains libnvblas.so

However, not all BLAS methods may be available, so you have to specify a fallback-BLAS library (like openblas).

For more details, see https://developer.nvidia.com/cublasxt

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a quick way on Ubuntu 20.04 with Cmake and CUDA.

### Install CUDA

This seems very difficult according to [the official guidance](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux), but on Ubuntu 20 using `apt` works fine.

```sh
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

After this, do not forget to set the environmental variable `NVBLAS_CONFIG_FILE` according to [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nvblas/#NVBLAS_CONFIG_FILE).
The default contents on the website will do except for changing the CPU BLAS library. For me, the `libopenblas.a` does not work and should be set as `libopenblas.so.0`.

### Use Cmake to Compile Armadillo

The manual installation seems to be complex for me, so I just make some adjustments to the `cmake` install method.

```sh
cmake . -Dopenblas_LIBRARY=<PATH TO NVBLAS LIB>/libnvblas.so
```

### Write Code Using Armadillo

The `cmake` project is just no different and no additional compiling flag is needed since they are all set when compiling the Armadillo library.

If anything went wrong, the log file (by default `nvblas.log`) will provide some information. It may be something like it can not open the CPU BLAS library.