# Armadillo C++ fails to diagonalize bigger matrices

Tags: c++, slurm, armadillo, intel-mkl

I'm working with the Armadillo linear algebra library for C++ to diagonalize large matrices up to 65k x 65k on a cluster operating with SLURM. For matrices larger than 30k x 30k i get the following error message:

```
Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 9 was incorrect on entry to DSYTRD.

Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 8 was incorrect on entry to DSTEDC.

Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 12 was incorrect on entry to DORMTR.
```

I assume this could be caused by using int32 instead of int64, even though I enabled the arma macros ARMA_USE_64bit, ARMA_USE_BLASS_LONG_LONG etc so the internal code should operate on 64-bit integers. Here is my compilation line

```
    g++ main.cpp IsingModel.cpp IsingModel_disorder.cpp IsingModel_sym.cpp tools.cpp\ user_interface.cpp -o Ising.o -pthread -I../LIBRARIES_CPP/armadillo-10.8.0/include/ \
-L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64 -fopenmp -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_core -lmkl_intel_ilp64\
 -lmkl_sequential  -lpthread -lm -lmkl_gnu_thread -lstdc++fs -llapack -fcx-fortran-rules\
 -fomit-frame-pointer -lblas -std=c++20 -std=c++17 -O3
```

For those, which know SLURM here are the modules I am using:

```
module load Armadillo/9.900.1-foss-2020a
module load imkl/2021.4.0
module load OpenBLAS/0.3.18-GCC-11.2.0
```

Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: Both `-std=c++20`and `-std=c++17`? Why? Where do the flags used in building come from?

Comment: oh, haha i did not realise that i have that, that is actually a mistake of mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I do not have enough reputation to comment below so I have to make it an answer.

During my use of Armadillo, I find the current version of Armadillo and Intel MKL does not work properly and can be buggy (Ubuntu 20). Indeed there have been a lot of reports of that but it's hard for us to do anything for it is the Armadillo library that links to these libraries. Maybe this can be [an issue](https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/-/issues) for the developers.

I myself find **OpenBlas** a good alternative to Intel MKL as the support for Armadillo. It is really efficient. Moreover, if you have an Nvidia GPU, NVBlas works well with OpenBlas. (A cmake solution to use NVBlas together with OpenBlas is detailed in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70860784/15080514).)
If you use `cmake` to install the Armadillo library, change the `CmakeLists.txt` file a bit to disable the detection of MKL.

#### CMake Solution

> If MKL is installed and it is *persistently giving problems* during linking,
> Support for MKL can be disabled by editing the `CMakeLists.txt` file,
> deleting `CMakeCache.txt` and re-running the cmake based installation.
> ([Armadillo README](https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code#9-support-for-openblas-and-intel-mkl))

In `CMakeLists.txt`, comment out the line ([Line 327](https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/-/blob/10.8.x/CMakeLists.txt#L327)) containing:

```
INCLUDE(ARMA_FindMKL)
```

#### g++ Solution

With `g++`, delete the linking library for Intel MKL, use `-lopenblas` for **OpenBlas**.

```
g++ main.cpp IsingModel.cpp IsingModel_disorder.cpp IsingModel_sym.cpp tools.cpp \
user_interface.cpp -o Ising.o -pthread -I../LIBRARIES_CPP/armadillo-10.8.0/include/ \
-fopenmp -lpthread -lm -lstdc++fs -llapack -fcx-fortran-rules \
-fomit-frame-pointer -lblas -lopenblas -std=c++20 -O3
```

Comment: what do you mean by OpenMP as alternative to Armadillo? OpenMP is tool for multithreading strategies. Nevertheless, I do not use cmake to install it, I load the existing module on the cluster, I can however link directly to blas/lapack using an Armadillo macro, however, I'm not sure how that works, whether stays the same

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, it is **OpenBlas** not OpenMP. I believe this is a problem of the linking of Armadillo and Intel MKL. From your question, I find you have Intel MKL and OpenBlas installed. They are all used to make some complex computations more efficient. You can find the related documentation [here](https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code#9-support-for-openblas-and-intel-mkl).

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry this could count as an answer if you include the relevant quotes from your links in your answer 

Comment: @Qant123 I have edited my answer and I hope it is more explicit now.